# Positioning of components in CSS and HTML

Tags: css, html

I'm having many issues regarding the positioning of div boxes in HTML and CSS. I have got a wrapper and 2 boxes. I want one box on the left and the other on the right, however the box on the right appears under the others. Why is this? I don't want to use "top" as it messes with a few other things. What do I do?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Harry Kitchener - Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="navbar"></div>
            <div id="newsbar"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

#wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#navbar
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
}

#newsbar
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
}
```

FIXED:

```
#wrapper
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#navbar
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
}

#newsbar
{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default display for a div is: "display: block".
Blocks don't obey "width" style and span as 100%. The following elements are put below the block-displayed div.

Try adding the style to your divs as "display: inline-block" (i.e. to those divs you want to see consecutive).

EDIT: did not fully understand the question fully. BESIDES doing what i told, you can put "float: left" and "float: right" to those divs if you want them to stick to the left and right respectively.

Answer (score 1):

add Float:left and float:right:

```
#navbar
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
float:left;
}

#newsbar
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is because the elements are position `relative` to each other.

You have multiple "solutions":

1) `float` your elements. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p3PJ/1/)

E.g.

```
#newsbar
{
    float: right;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
}
```

2) Change your positioning to be `fixed`, but likely you want `absolute`. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p3PJ/)

E.g.

```
#newsbar
{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #A13927;
}
```

3) Other options as well (display: table-cell, et cetera)

Comment: Great! Be sure to select the Answer which you used as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have a ton of solutions for this one. Here are three ways of doing it, each method will produce slightly different results. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs3gA/)

HTML:

```
<div class="method-1">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="method-2">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="method-3">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div div {
    height: 10em;
    width: 15%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

div.method-1 div {
    display: inline-block;
}
div.method-2 {
    height: 10em;
}
div.method-2 div {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

div.method-2 div.right {
    left: 15%;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

div.method-3 {
    display: table;
    width: 30%;
}
div.method-3 div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```